# I do not want the appearance of the writing pad, but when you press

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have a problem in Edittext, When you open the Activity , the clavier opened . 
I want the board not appear until you press it .
example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GppYS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following line of code inside your Activity's onCreate() method.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your focus is on the editText onCreate the activity and that's why the keyboard is opened. Try with this one directly in the onCreate method of your activity ( it will hide the keyboard everytime the activty starts ):

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or this one:

```
edittext.clearFocus();
```

And one more solution is this tutorial (create a single Linearlayout, which doesn't have content and is invisible in this case, on which is the focus when you start the activity): http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/remove-autofocus-edittext-android